# instanceof LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I'm creating a LinkedHashMap using the following code-

```
private final Map<Long, DD> cachedPlansById=new LinkedHashMap<Long, DD>();

cachedPlansById instanceof LinkedHashMap
```

But I I'm getting a 'true' on instanceof HashMap and a 'false' on instanceof LinkedHashMap.
Can you please suggest how to make sure it is true for instanceof LinkedHashMap?

I can't declare it as LinkedHashMap, that breaks the code.

It's true that when I write a new test class, the above code works. Not sure what's the problem in my original class, since there are not even any imports to HashMap and cachedPlansById only gets instantiated once, so not sure how it gets shadowed.
Here's the test class-

```
import java.util.*;

public class MapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Long, String> m = new LinkedHashMap<Long, String>();
        if (m instanceof LinkedHashMap) {
            System.out.println("true");
            LinkedHashMap<Long, String> l = (LinkedHashMap) m;
            if (l instanceof LinkedHashMap)
                System.out.println("true");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: code or it didn't happen

Comment: It should return true for both

Comment: It returns true. Are you sure you have tried it?

Comment: can you check the import for your code if they are correct. Once i used apache map instead of java util ...

Comment: Then show us exactly your code that reproduces the problem, not just some gist like you have now in your question. By you by any chance make your own class named `LinkedHashMap`? If yes then remove it.

Comment: Here's the import-import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

Comment: Post something that compiles and exhibits the problem. This is necessary because the problem is clearly not in the two lines you quoted.

Comment: Not only that, when I do LinkedHashMap l=(LinkedHashMap)cachedPlansById; I get a class cast exception.

Comment: Look, are you going to post us a compilable test case with the problem or not? Without it, no-one will be able to help you. My money is on shadowing.

Comment: You will want to edit your current question with a full and complete example of the problem.

Comment: How is it getting shadowed if there is just 1 declaration of cachedPlansById in this class? And the instanceof is done in the same class.

Comment: If it ain't shadowed, you might be assigning a new value to `cachedPlansById`, which is a `HashMap` and not a `LinkedHashMap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running this code in a JUnit test and it passes, so they all return true.

```
Map<Long, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Long, String>();
assertTrue(LinkedHashMap.class.isAssignableFrom(map.getClass()));
assertTrue(map instanceof LinkedHashMap);
assertTrue(HashMap.class.isAssignableFrom(map.getClass()));
assertTrue(map instanceof HashMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

But this code returns both true

As child is in fact an instance of Parent so obviously LinkedHashMap object will be an instance of its superclass HashMap and secondly LinkedHashMap will obviously be an instance of LinkedHashMap

```
final Map map = new LinkedHashMap();
if(map instanceof LinkedHashMap){
    System.out.println("true");
}
if(map instanceof HashMap){
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I changed the object type from HashMap to LinkedHashMap using hot deploy while debugging. Once I ran the same code after building again, I got the right behavior. Thanks for your answers. 
Original-

```
private final Map<Long, DD> cachedPlansById = new HashMap<Long, DD>();
```

New-

```
private final Map<Long, DD> cachedPlansById = new LinkedHashMap<Long, DD>();
```